# Since when is a log distributed across a finite sum?

Tags: expression-manipulation, series-expansion

I have this:

```
$ord = 9;

eq = X^Q - V^P ((V - 1)^Q/(c^(P - Q) (V - c^2)^Q)) /. Q -> 2 /. 
P -> 3 

VV = Series[Sum[a[i] X^i, {i, 0, $ord}], {X, 0, $ord}]

Solve[((eq /. X -> 0) == 0), V]

VV = VV /. a[0] -> 1

ef = Solve[Series[(eq /. V -> VV), {X, 0, $ord}] == 0, 
  Table[a[i], {i, 1, $ord}]]

aa = VV /. Flatten[ef] // Simplify

L = Log[Series[aa, {X, 0, $ord - 1}]]/X // Simplify

Expand[Coefficient[L, X]]
```

which is great in that it gives me what I want and expect. However, I don't understand how the Log[Series[aa,... term distributes a logarithm through a series. Is it just the case that some magnificent simplification occurs? I mean, how does the algorithm in Mathematica even start this? Is the implementation (with the assumption of bounds on the argument):

```
Log[Z] = Sum[(((z-1)^j)/j)*(-1)^(j+1),j=1..infinity]
```

I guess I just find it amazing that there are no Log terms left and a polynomial remains. Can someone enlighten me?

Thanks!

Comment: Please look at the [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) for $\log(1+x)$. You get the same result.

Comment: I was playing around with converting it to a Taylor series, but now I see I can use your suggestion and, assuming bounds are ok, just get power series of truncated polynomials, which can be expanded, almost 'iteratively', as a power series again. Thanks for the insight! Still amazes me that is leaves a polynomial...

Answer (score 2):

It is not `Log` "distributing" through a `Series`, but it is how *Mathematica* calculates the composition of functions and series, at least when the function has a known series expansion.

```
Log[Series[f[x], {x, 0, 2}]] // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Series[Log[f[x]], {x, 0, 2}] // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is done with the regular calculus/algebra definition of the [composition of power series](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CompositionAndInversionOfPowerSeries.html), (see also [Formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Composition_of_series) or [Brent and Kung](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.131.5030)).

```
ComposeSeries[Series[Log[x], {x, f[0], 2}], Series[f[x], {x, 0, 2}]] // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The OP's result has `f[0] == 1`, so the only `Log` term vanishes.

However, note *Mathematica* won't expand an unknown function automatically.  So if we reverse the composition of `Log` and `f`, we get

```
Series[f[Log[x]], {x, 1, 2}]
f@Series[Log[x], {x, 1, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I suppose the reason is that if the user passes `f` inside `Series`, *Mathematica* will treat `f` as analytic, assuming the user meant it to be.  But if `f` is outside `Series`, *Mathematica* does not assume `f` to be analytic.